# Please Help with localizing asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, localization

i would like to add localization to my app... the app is currently not using any kind of localization and the strings are just being injected directly into the views... so i would obviously need to change that.... what I would like is my master page to have two flag icons.. spain and england... and every view could be displayed in either spanish or english by clicking on the flag...  I have created two global resource files.. Strings.en.resx and Strings.es.resx with just one entry each
welcome_message.. with different values for each, of course... now what I need to know is how can I change between one or the other?? I want to be able to change the language any time I want but I also need a way to keep the selected language between requests (maybe in session?)

I know this isnt mvc related as much as asp.net framework...

please help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html This link has a lot of helpful information regarding localization in MVC. It goes through step by step what you need to do to achieve your goal.